# Ask client which file you would like to process

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a Macro to help my teammate to update the file automictically
if I want to modify it to...

1. Ask the client which multiple file you want to convert?
2. looping and convert the file
3. END

here is the code I copy from internet.
Thank you!

```
Sub AllEDIFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
  
    folderPath = "C:\Users\"'change to suit
    
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")
    Do While filename <> ""
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
         
        
        Call EDI

        
        filename = Dir
    Loop
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox ("Done!")
  
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what is the question? Maybe you have a look at [GetOpenFilename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) in order to get started.

Comment: Also, you might consider modifying the `EDI` procedure, e.g. `Sub EDI(ByVal wb As Workbook)` and call it using `EDI wb`. Best share it so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the macro to open a window for the user to select a file you could use:

```
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
```